# Is there an extension or mode in Emacs similar to surround.vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, surround

[Surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) is a nifty vim extension that allows you to surround blocks of text with , brackets, braces, and pretty much any arbitrary "surround" character. It supports paragraph and word surround, but I frequently use it in visual mode.
I'm playing around with Emacs and wondering if there's something similar; something that will let me highlight a region and then have the marked region (or rectangle) enclosed with braces, brackets or tags.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023770/automatically-closing-braces-in-emacs

Comment: I ended up using Vimpulse-surround: https://github.com/timcharper/vimpulse-surround.el

Comment: _edit_ [Evil-surround](https://github.com/timcharper/evil-surround) is the new vimpulses-surround.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe [wrap-region](http://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region) is what you need.

[smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) is another excellent option if need to wrap something with delimiters, tags, etc.

Comment: Corral (https://github.com/nivekuil/corral) has just come out that also does this.

Comment: Note that Corral's usage model is different and does not appear to honor wrapping the selection.

Answer (score 9):

I use [evil-surround](https://github.com/timcharper/evil-surround). It emulates vim behaviour but unfortunately might not be what most emacs users want since it requires the [evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) vim mode.
However, it may or may not be right for you since you referenced surround.vim in the first place.

evil-surround seems to support most of the features in Surround.vim, including modifying surroundings.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is anything built in for tags, but for parens you can do <kbd>M-(</kbd>.  For brackets/braces/quotes you could do:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'insert-pair)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-{") 'insert-pair)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-\"") 'insert-pair)
```

Note that if you don't have a region highlighted, it will just insert the pair of whatevers and put the cursor in between them.  Also handy for deleting matching whatevers is

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-)") 'delete-pair)
```

If you want to insert tag pairs, it's some simple elisp:

```
(defun my-insert-tags (tag)
  (interactive "sTag: ")
  (if (region-active-p)
      (let ((beg (region-beginning)))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (region-end))
          (insert "</" tag ">")
          (goto-char beg)
          (insert "<" tag ">")))
    (insert "<" tag ">")
    (save-excursion
      (insert "</" tag ">"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of any way of doing that in Emacs, not even with a module.

My Elisp is a little rusty, buy here's a simple function that will enclose the current region (marked text) or word with quotes ("):

```
(defun insert-quotes ()
  "Inserts quotes (\") around the current region or work."
  (interactive)
  (let (start end bounds)
    (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
        (setq start (region-beginning) 
              end (region-end))
      (progn
        (setq bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
        (setq start (car bounds) 
              end (cdr bounds))))
    (goto-char start)
    (insert "\"")
    (goto-char (+ end 1))
    (insert "\"")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a clone of surround.vim, as of 1 week ago: http://github.com/timcharper/vimpulse-surround.el

It requires vimpulse, which requires vim.  It implements much of surround.vim's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

maybe [evil-surround](https://github.com/timcharper/evil-surround) is what you are looking for.

thanks.

Answer (score -3):

So you want to select a region or similar and then make a box around it like a various modes do for comments? I believe emacs-wiki (http://www.emacswiki.org/) has some ascii-line art (and a figlet tool as well) that will do that. Searching for box, quite, line art ...

```
############################
#                           #
# I AM REGION, WE ARE  MANY #
#                           #
############################
```