# Set Emacs to smart auto-line after a parentheses pair?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have `electric-pair-mode` on (which isn't really particularly relevant, as this could apply to any auto-pairing mode or even manual parens), but in a nutshell, I'd like it so that in the case I have:

`function foo() {|}`

(where `|` is the mark)

If I press enter, I would like to have it automatically go to

```
function foo() {
|
}
```

It would also mean that

`function foo(|) {}`

would become

```
function foo(
|
){}
```

I already have things to take care of the indentation, but I'm not sure how to say "if I'm inside any empty pair of matched parenthesis, when I press return, actually insert two new lines and put me at the first one".

Thanks!

Comment: you want the second case as well?  Or that would be a side-effect?

Comment: the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801147/how-can-can-i-get-emacs-to-insert-closing-braces-automatically) combined should tell you how to do this

Comment: The second case should be a side effect -- but I don't see how the answers provided work then.

The case you linked to is explicitly replacing "{" -- this that I'm suggesting/asking about would replace everything that fits a matched parens.

Comment: I suppose the pseudocode would be something like:

    `On RET: 
      if move_mark_left.matchParens() is move_mark_right:
        RET, RET, up`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I have in my init file, I got this from Magnar Sveen's [`.emacs.d`](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d)

```
(defun new-line-dwim ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((break-open-pair (or (and (looking-back "{") (looking-at "}"))
                             (and (looking-back ">") (looking-at "<"))
                             (and (looking-back "(") (looking-at ")"))
                             (and (looking-back "\\[") (looking-at "\\]")))))
    (newline)
    (when break-open-pair
      (save-excursion
        (newline)
        (indent-for-tab-command)))
    (indent-for-tab-command)))
```

You can bind it to a key of your choice. I have bound it to `M-RET` but if you want, you can bind it to `RET`. The lines

```
(or (and (looking-back "{") (looking-at "}"))
    (and (looking-back ">") (looking-at "<"))
    (and (looking-back "(") (looking-at ")"))
    (and (looking-back "\\[") (looking-at "\\]")))
```

check if cursor is at `{|}`, `[|]`, `(|)` or `>|<` (html).

Comment: Thanks! Almost exactly what I was looking for. It's a shame the paren-match has to be explicit rather than algorithmic, though.

Comment: Assuming the modes you're using assign `(` and `)` char-syntax for the delimiters you want, `(and (eq ?\( (char-syntax (char-before))) (eq ?\) (char-syntax (char-after))))` will work. For example this will cover `() [] {}` in `java-mode`. But not `><` -- not even in `html-mode`. Still, that makes it mostly "algorithmic".

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to look into [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens). Specifically, see the page on [insertion hooks](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Permissions#insertion-specification).

Here's the config I personally use:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'smartparens
  (sp-with-modes
      '(c++-mode objc-mode c-mode)
    (sp-local-pair "{" nil :post-handlers '(:add ("||\n[i]" "RET")))))
```

This has the added benefit of indenting the current line automatically as well. This can easily be generalized to more modes (using `sp-pair` for global pairs) and paren types (just duplicate the code), if you please.