# New line and autoindent braces in ccmode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

I'm using Emacs. I want that when I write this (| is the point):

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {|
```

And I press Enter (or a different key, whatever), I get this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   |
}
```

So I can start typing right away the content of the block, and the block is automatically closed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my C/C++ setup that solves your problem:

```lisp
(defun ins-c++-curly ()
  "Insert {}.
Threat is as function body when from endline before )"
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "\\()\\|try\\|else\\|const\\|:\\)$")
      (progn
        (insert " {\n\n}")
        (indent-according-to-mode)
        (forward-line -1)
        (indent-according-to-mode))
    (insert "{}")
    (backward-char)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-common-hook)

(defun my-c-common-hook ()
  (define-key c-mode-base-map "{" 'ins-c++-curly))
```

And here's the [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) for `for`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
#name : for (...; ...; ...) { ... }
# --
for (unsigned int ${1:i}=0; $1<${2:N}; ++$1)$0
```

Note that the snippet doesn't do curly braces, so I can decide if I want them
or just a single statement.

And just to show you the sequence of keys that leads me from zero to the code
in your question: `for` <kbd>C-o</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close character automatically, `M-x electric-pair-mode` may be useful(Emacs version 24 or later required). Just try it and see it matches your need.

[AutoPairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs)

And I think below also may be helpful.

[Set Emacs to smart auto-line after a parentheses pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107501/set-emacs-to-smart-auto-line-after-a-parentheses-pair)